# php ssh2_scp_recv and ssh2_scp_send always return error windows sftp server?

Tags: php, windows, ssh, sftp, file-transfer

`ssh2_scp_recv` and `ssh2_scp_send` always returning the following error:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: ssh2_scp_send(): Failure creating remote file: Unexpected channel close

Severity: Warning
Message: ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file
```

When I connect to my Windows sftp file server OpenSSH for windows 7.3p1-1
the client also a windows php iis environment with php ssh2 0.12 x64 for windows

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("myserver.com", 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);


$sftp_send = ssh2_scp_send($connection, "$_upload_path"."myfile", "$_remote_folder_path/myfile", 0644 );


$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}{$_remote_folder_path}");
 while (false != ($entry = readdir($handle))){

  if ($entry == "." || $entry == "..")
      continue;  
   echo $entry;

 $sftp_recv = ssh2_scp_recv ($connection,  $_remote_folder_path."/".$entry , $_download_path.$entry );
}
```

Comment: `scp` is not `sftp`.

Comment: Does SCP work using any other SCP client? PSCP for example (with `-scp` switch). Why do you even use SCP?

Comment: i have to call opendir over sftp to list all file in the directory and ten call ssh2_scp_recv to copy the file to local system.
i have tried some scp client like pscp and winscp, and it is work.